# What is the significance of the broken departure board and tray table?

Tags: plot-explanation, final-destination

What is the significance of the broken departure board and tray table in Final Destination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like simple foreshadowing to me (especially the tray table.)  Things are breaking apart in little ways, foreshadowing the forthcoming explosion that kicks off the movie's primary plot line.